# android-studio, cannot resolve symbol SQLiteOpenHelper,Context

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

I create an Android project dependency by the greenDAO [greenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/introduction/)

and create a modual greendao-lib with greeenDAO ,but it's not work. see :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCNJu.jpg)

and this is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // android core
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    // green dao lib
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.1.0'
    // javax annotation
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    // lombok
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.2'
    // guava
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Try move cursor on the red word and press Alt+Enter.

Comment: alt+Enter, there's no suggestion useful; just all tell me to create a SQLiteDatabase, or Context

Answer (score 2):

kindly check your import section, it should be like as follows.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Comment: I've made a module of java library, you mean, I should make a android library ?

Comment: I don't know what's java library.But I think android library contains java library.